# Составить SQL-запрос: вывести сотрудников, отработавших менее 8 часов в день

Tags: запрос, sql

В компании работает несколько тысяч сотрудников. Для учета их рабочего времени используется специальное аппаратное и программное обеспечение, которое фиксирует начало и конец рабочего времени, сохраняя его в таблице:

```
CREATE TABLE sessions (
  wnum integer not null,  – персональный номер сотрудника
  work_start datetime not null,  – время начала работы
  work_end datetime not null  – время окончания работы
);
```

У некоторой части сотрудников свободный график, некоторые могут работать из дома.

Также существует таблица, в которой хранятся все уважительные причины отсутствия на работе (отпуск, плохое самочувствие и т.д.).

```
CREATE TABLE excuse (
  wnum integer not null,  - персональный номер сотрудника (совпадает с wnum в sessions) 
  absent_start datetime not null,  – время с которого сотрудник отсутствовал
  absent_end datetime not null  – время до которого сотрудник отсутствовал
);
```

Необходимо составить SQL-запрос, который будет выводить работников, отработавших менее 8 часов за рабочий день в прошлом месяце. Результат должен состоять из следующего набора колонок:

```
wnum – персональный номер сотрудника
work_day – день, когда данный работник отработал менее 8 часов
work_time – количество времени, отработанное в данный день
```

Детали:

- т. к. часть работников имеет свободный график, а часть может работать из дома, то в течение дня может быть несколько записей о начале и конце работы (например, работник предпочитает 4 часа отработать утром и 4 вечером). Кроме того, работник может начать работать в одни сутки, а закончить в другие, или даже через сутки, в таком случае данные временные отрезки нужно разделять дополнительно. Например, работник начал работать 22-го числа в 22:00, а закончил 24-го в 02:00, тогда в 22-е и 24-ое число необходимо записать по 2 рабочих часа, а  в 23-е — 24 часа.
- отсутствие на работе по уважительной причине (таблица excuse) не считается нерабочим временем. Если работник отработал 4 часа и 4 часа не был на рабочем месте по уважительной причине, то в итоговый отчет он попасть не должен.
- если работник не был целый день на работе без уважительной причины, то он тоже должен попасть в отчет (work_time – 0 часов).
- в отчет не должны попадать суббота и воскресенье, даже если работник работал в эти дни.
- запрос должен быть максимально экономичным, насколько это возможно

**Заранее благодарю.**

Comment: И что уже сделано? На какой СУБД? Напомню, что [на форуме не стоит задавать вопросы с просьбой выполнить бесплатно или за деньги какую-либо работу, связанную с программированием: форум не является фриланс-биржей.](http://hashcode.ru/faq/)

Answer (score 3):

Задача не сложная. Нужно двигаться поэтапно:

1. Вам понадобится таблица дней. Ее можно формировать на лету (создавать временную таблицу), а лучше вести календарь по дням. Календари бывают полезны с точки зрения законодательства - переносы праздников, в частности, а также выходные вам нужно обрабатывать отдельно (с различными графиками работы, вам вероятно придется также столкнуться в будущем, бывает не только пятидневка).
2. Далее выбираете для каждого дня варианты попадания интервалов работы:

   - Начало и конец работы попадают целиком в день
   - В день попадает только начало, конец в другом дне
   - В день попадает только конец, начало было раньше
   - День целиком в работе - начало работы меньше начала дня, конец работы больше конца дня
3. Для каждого варианта считаете количество отработанных часов как сумму часов по всем записям, соответствующим данному виду интервала (актуально только для первого варианта)
4. Складываете полученные часы  по всем вариантам, таким образом получаете количество отработанных часов за день.
5. С причинами отсутствия поступать нужно аналогично рабочим часам. Если нет наложения интервалов работы и отсутствия (типа работал и отсутствовал одновременно), то просто надо добавить часы отсутствия как рабочие часы и все.
6. Дальше полученный набор уже можно будет отфильтровать по 8 часам, выходным... Например, сделать этот запрос вложенным, выбирать из него уже суммированные данные.

Чтобы запрос был экономичным, видимо это означает как минимум быстрым, нужно добавить будет индексы. Правильными видятся составные индексы на обе даты...